# angular ng serve not getting the correct path

Tags: angular, path, angular-router

I have a project with a router module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';


const routes : Routes = [
    {
        path : '',
        loadChildren : './pages/main/main.module#MainModule'
    },{
        path : 'ajout',
        loadChildren : './free/free.module#FreeModule'
    },{
        path : '**',
        loadChildren : './pages/four/four.module#FourModule'
    }
]
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
        //initialNavigation: 'enabled',
        //enableTracing : true
    })],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Here is where it is strange, 
it was working fine a few hours ago, then all of sudden, when I go to localhost:4200, the FreeModule gets loaded.

I tried for hours not figuring why, so I did build the app and check the build...
On the build, localhost:4000, the MainModule is loaded (so it is correct), but I do not understand why on the :4200, the wrong module gets loaded... I even restarted ng serve many time...

What am I missing here? I am totally lost

EDIT : 
I did try to simply remove :

```
{
    path : '',
    loadChildren : './pages/main/main.module#MainModule'
}
```

And still the FreeModule gets loaded when I navigate to the root, so it seems like fr some reason the angular app has configured (by itself?) a default route... How can I get rid of that...? I do not want to start the app from scratch

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
{
    path : '',
    loadChildren : './pages/main/main.module#MainModule',
    pathMatch: 'full'
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I just tried it and still load the wrong module

Answer (score 0):

It turned out, I was importing all the modules into a shared modules resulting in this weird behavior and also removing the lazy loading aspect...
I removed those modules and now all working fine